# Runnable is not garbage collected in java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have seen many Thread java examples and Runnable objects are created as tasks and passed to thread.
As there is no reference to these tasks, so why is this task not garbage collected by java?
Or is garbage collected and I am asking the wrong question here?
Please share your valuable thoughts.

Comment: How do you know they aren't being garbage collected?

Comment: @nneonneo I like the question +1, I wanted to ask the same thing :). ok so one more: `How do you know they aren't being garbage collected`?

Comment: @elbek I didn't test this part, but I was logically concluding that if it is being garbage collected then nothing will work and something must be more to it than what meets the eye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you don't have an explicit reference to an object doesn't mean that an internal JVM object doesn't hold one to it.

Take an example:

```
frame.add(new JButton("foobar"));
```

There is no reference to it from a developer point of view but internally the frame has a list of components. This is what happen with threads, the internal scheduler must keep a reference to them for sure.

The thread itself will be garbage collected just when released from the scheduler (so that no reference effectively exists to it anymore)